# save new record entered from Datagridview into the database

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, dataset, datatableadapters

Am using a DataSet and a TableAdapter to populate a Datagridview. The Datagridview allows inserting new records at the bottom. Now when I enter values for the new record in the Datagridview, the record is not automatically saved back to the database. Which event do U need to handle or what code do I need to write to get the new record saved back to the databse.

am using C#.

Comment: do you populate the gridview with code (if yes please post it) or with a DataSource?

Comment: Windows Forms or Web Forms? Can you show the code you use to bind the data to the grid?

Comment: i populate the DataGridView with a TableAdapter and its a windows forms application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling the `Update()` method on the `TableAdapter`? The following code comes from [MSDN's discussion on the `TableAdapter`:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
try 
{
    this.Validate();
    this.customersBindingSource.EndEdit();

    this.customersTableAdapter.Update(this.northwindDataSet.Customers);
    MessageBox.Show("Update successful"); 
} 
catch (System.Exception ex) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Update failed"); 
}
```

There are various places where you can put this sort of logic - as Davide Piras suggests you could have a Save button on your form or if you want data to be saves as each row is entered you can have your save logic with the RowValidated event handler.

Answer (score 1):

you can put somewhere a Save button and when user click that button you call a method like this:

```
private void UpdateDataSet(DataSet dataSet)
{
    // Check for changes with the HasChanges method first.
    if(!dataSet.HasChanges(DataRowState.Modified)) return;

    // Create temporary DataSet variable and
    // GetChanges for modified rows only.
    DataSet tempDataSet = 
        dataSet.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);

    // Check the DataSet for errors.
    if(tempDataSet.HasErrors)
    {
        // Insert code to resolve errors.
    }
    // After fixing errors, update the data source with  
    // the DataAdapter used to create the DataSet.
    adapter.Update(tempDataSet);
}
```